# 1.9 RWD default theme footer link layout fix

Tags: layout, footer

This is a solution to the layout problem for the footer links at screen sizes smaller than 599px:

**Edit the CSS from:**

.footer .links:nth-child(odd) { margin-right: 3.125%; clear: both;}

**to:**

.footer .links:nth-child(odd) { margin-right: 3.125%; }

.footer .links:nth-child(even) { clear: both; }

You'll end up with this layout:

[image: Default 1.9 Magento Theme Footer]

Comment: Would you mind to rephrase your questions as a QUESTION and post this answer as an answer? :D